# @Transactional not an annotation

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I am trying to rebuild a grails application using ggts 3.4.0 with groovy 2.1.8, grails 2.3.3 and java 1.7.

In the services files I'm getting these error messages:

> Groovy.class grails.transaction.Transactional is not an annotation in @grails.transaction.Transactional

I believe that one of the components listed above is causing this problem. Can someone suggest which particular one and the required version I need?

Incidentally, I've successfully built this in the past with different versions of the various components but I'm not sure what they were. I do have backups - so if you can suggest where can I find details of these builds that would help.

I would welcome any suggestions?

-mike

Comment: http://docs.grails.org/2.3.x/guide/services.html try `import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`

Comment: Grails is SUPER PICKY about having matching Grails versions in the tooling (GGTS, etc) and the Grails project you're working with. GGTS 3.4.0 is for Grails 2.2.x, not Grails 2.3.x. For Grails 2.3.x, try GGTS 3.5.0: http://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/v350/NewAndNoteworthy.html. As vahid alluded to, the issue you're having is that a service or controller is trying to import @Transactional from the package as defined by Grails 2.3.3, which doesn't match the Grails version in your tooling. So even if you fix that import, you'll run into other issues unless you use the proper version of the tools.

Comment: @emmanuel can you suggest where I can download older versions of GGTS such as 3.5.0, from? The News&NoteWorthy link points to the most recent , 3.6.4, but I cannot see where I can get older versions. Ideally I don't want to move to a higher version for the reasons you mention.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find a download for it. You may have to use another IDE. See http://docs.grails.org/2.3.3/guide/gettingStarted.html#ide